# The UILabel font sizes I have set in IB for my labels are all defaulted to 12 (both custom and system fonts)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, fonts, interface-builder

I have tried subclassing the label and setting the size programmatically, as well as messing around with the attributes in the inspector. I've used custom fonts and system font, this doesn't change either.

What could be causing this to happen?

**This is the subclass I tried out**

```
class robotoHeading1Label: UILabel {

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    //self.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Medium", size: 36)
    self.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(36)
    self.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
}
}
```

**EDIT**
So for some reason, what wasn't working before is working now, which is using `label.font = UIFont (name" Roboto-Medium", size: 36)`
in the actaul ViewController where the label is being displayed.

for some reason my UILabel Subclass is crashing when I try link my labels to it, this is what it looks like:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

@IBDesignable class robotoHeading1Label: UILabel {

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Medium", size: 36)

    }
}
```

**Here is the label's inspector in IB:**
[image]

Comment: Is you apply height constraint on UILabel?

Comment: No, I currently have no constraints. But when I do apply height, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Are you sure that this initialiser is called?

Comment: Yeah. I put breakpoints in there to make sure.

Comment: can you upload the image of  UILabel Attribute Inspector?

Comment: Remove @IBDesignable as its  properties provide new access to an old feature: user-defined runtime attributes. http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/